# Extract a number of continuous digits from a random string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to parse this list of strings that contains ID values as a series of 7 digits but I am not sure how to approach this.

```
lst1=[
    "(Tower 3rd fl floor_WINDOW CORNER : option 2_ floor cut out_small_wood) : GA -   
Floors : : Model Lines : id 3925810 
(Tower 3rd fl floor_WINDOW CORNER : option 2_ floor cut out_small_wood) : GA - Floors : Floors : Floor : Duke new core floors : id 3925721",
        "(Tower 3rd fl floor_WINDOW CORNER : option 3_ floor cut out_large_wood) : GA - Floors : : Model Lines : id 3976019 
(Tower 3rd fl floor_WINDOW CORNER : option 3_ floor cut out_large_wood) : GA - Floors : Floors : Floor : Duke new core floors : id 3975995"
        ]
```

I really want to pull out just the digit values and combine them into one string separated by a colon ";". 
The resulting list would be something like this:

```
lst1 = ["3925810; 3925721", "3976019; 3975995"]
```

Comment: Your code is riddled with syntax errors.

Comment: well those strings come from parsing an HTML file. It really is just two instances from a list that is like 1000 instances long. It is not really code, but information about certain objects in a model so it's text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression, like this

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"\bid\s*?(\d+)")
print ["; ".join(pattern.findall(item)) for item in lst1]
# ['3925810; 3925721', '3976019; 3975995']
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/WjsdMuFf3Ajy4sfR)

If you want to make sure that the numbers you pick will only be of length 7, then you can do it like this

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\bid\s*?(\d{7})\D*?")
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4fFYJ9l06fEJScay)

The `\b` refers to the word boundary. So, it makes sure that `id` will be a separate word and it is followed by 0 or more whitespace characters. And then we match numeric digits `[0-9]`, `\d` is just a shorthand notation for the same. `{7}` matches only seven times and followed by `\D`, its the inverse of `\d`.

Comment: Nice - almost the same as I've posted in the duplicate thread :)

Comment: @alecxe Looks like OP edited the other question after you answered.

Comment: so this almost works but for a string instance like this "(Tower 3rd floor_Wood Walls : Option 1 lower shelves only) : Workset1 : Walls : Basic Wall : Tower Wood wall - 18" : id 5300208 
(Tower 3rd floor_Wood Walls : Option 1 lower shelves only) : Workset1 : Walls : 3rd fl chamfer void 2 : 3rd fl chamfer void 1 : id 5300288" it will return "5300208; 2; 1; 5300288". Is there a reason why it picks up those two extra digits?

Comment: yes, guys I am really sorry for the edits i am still finding my way around stack overflow and how to properly format those posts. i was trying to make those ids bold and added ** ** before and after and that threw off the answer. i am sorry.

Comment: @konrad Ah, I see... I fixed it now. Can you please try this?

Comment: @thefourtheye you may also want to improve it by asking for exactly 7 digits (as OP noted).

Comment: @alecxe Sure, done. Please check now :-)

Comment: this is great. I never heard of debuggex before. thanks!

Comment: so do i understand this correctly? \bid defines a boundary that starts on the left of "id" string. then you add a white space  \s what does *? mean? does it mean that there could be a number of spaces? then you define a group that contain only digits (\d+) right? I am trying to understand regular expressions since i never used them before.

Comment: @konrad `*` means match 0 or more times, but in this case it doesnt matter if we use `?` or not. It just tries to match as minimum as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is meant to be:

```
lst1=[
    "(Tower 3rd fl floor_WINDOW CORNER : option 2_ floor cut out_small_wood) : GA -   Floors : : Model Lines : id 3925810",
    "(Tower 3rd fl floor_WINDOW CORNER : option 2_ floor cut out_small_wood) : GA - Floors : Floors : Floor : Duke new core floors : id 3925721",
    "(Tower 3rd fl floor_WINDOW CORNER : option 3_ floor cut out_large_wood) : GA - Floors : : Model Lines : id 3976019",
    "(Tower 3rd fl floor_WINDOW CORNER : option 3_ floor cut out_large_wood) : GA - Floors : Floors : Floor : Duke new core floors : id 3975995"
        ]
```

This will do the trick:

```
lst2 = [i.rsplit(" ",1)[1] for i in lst1]
```

which gives:

```
['3925810', '3925721', '3976019', '3975995']
```